# Why are arrows not working for input type number that I've used innerHTML on?

Tags: javascript, html, input, innerhtml

After I've used `.innerHTML` to replace a button with an input, the number is not changing its value if I click on both arrows.

Can you explain me why the second input is working properly but the one from the javascript is not?

```js
const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-btn");
resetButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
document.getElementById("reset-btn").innerHTML = '<input id="number" type="number" style="width:50px">';
});
```

```html
<button id="reset-btn">Change Table Nr.</button> 
<input id="number" type="number" style="width:50px">
```

Comment: Could you add the code as a stack Snippet? its the code icon when you edit your question

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: because you put a input inside of a button..... and that button still has a click event... I am amazed the engine is rendering the input inside of the button.

Comment: its because you're putting the input inside the button with .innerHTML instead of replacing it, when you click on the arrows it also triggers click event on the button, and everything inside the button including the input will be removed and replaced with a new input field. You can remove the event listener after the first click for it to work

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have placed the number field within a button. Instead of this, place both button and text field it within a div and hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, when you click on the input buttons, you also click on the button containing the input; and your script replaces the content of your button.

That's why you get that behaviour.

```js
const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-btn");

resetButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) return; // ignore clicks that bubbled up (from the input)
  
  resetButton.innerHTML = '<input id="number" type="number" style="width:50px">';
});
```

```html
<button id="reset-btn">Change Table Nr.</button>
<input id="number" type="number" style="width:50px">
```